# How to prove that a recursive function with inner summation is approximately equal to some closed-form equation?

Tags: summation, proof-writing, recurrence-relations, closed-form, recursive-algorithms

The following problem is taken from an algorithms textbook(specifically, in the context of complexity analysis of recursive algorithms.)

> Starting from the equation:
>   $$nf(n) = n(n-1) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k-1)$$ 
>   Prove that:
>   $$f(n)\approx 1.44n \log(n)$$

How would you go about this problem?

I tried to approach this problem by proving it with induction, but I couldn't make it hold for the inductive step(due to them being *approximately* equal). I also tried expanding the function recursively, but I couldn't find any recurring patterns to generalize. I must be missing something.

Comment: Is the value of $f(0)$ given? Are any values of $f$ given at any $n$? Also, $log(n)$ is not defined at $n = 0$, but the summation for $f$ includes $f(0)$, so it seems like the value of $f(0)$ should be given.

Comment: Since we can express $f(n)$ in terms of $f(0)$ for any value of $n,$ the question makes no sense unless $f(0)$ is known.  (I mean, $F(1)=2f(0), f(2)=1+3f(0),$ and so on.  Since $f(n)$ is apparently the time to solve a problem of size $n$, I would guess we're  supposed to take $f(0)=0.$